# Checking if a User's Input is in Range and is an Integer (Java)

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

I am working on a project (a game) and one of the requirements is to have warnings if they enter an option outside of the range (1-8) and if they enter a character. If the user enters an invalid number, the menu appears and asks them again which option they would like. If they enter a character, the program should ask them to enter an integer and ask for input again. This is what I have so far. It correctly identifies a number out of range and recalls the menu. It also identifies a character (invalid input), but does open input for the user to enter a correct option. How can I check both conditions?

Thanks,
Tyler

```
            int userChoice = scnr.nextInt();//<-- use this variable
            if (userChoice.hasNextInt() == false)
            {
                System.out.println("Error: Menu selection must be an integer! Please try again:");
            }
            // Variable used for storing what the user's main menu choice
            if (0 > userChoice || userChoice > 8)
            {
                System.out.println("Error: Invalid Menu Selection.");
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Available Actions:");
                System.out.println("(1) Print Market Prices");
                System.out.println("(2) Print Detailed Statistics");
                System.out.println("(3) Buy Some Sheep");
                System.out.println("(4) Buy a Guard Dog");
                System.out.println("(5) Sell a Sheep");
                System.out.println("(6) Sell a Guard Dog");
                System.out.println("(7) Enter Night Phase");
                System.out.println("(8) Quit");
                System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
                userChoice = scnr.nextInt();
            }
```

Comment: You're checking `hasNExtInt()` after you've gotten the `int`.

Comment: Where should I check it?

Answer (score 0):

you are using the `hasNextInt()` method on primitive `int` to see if the input is interger. instead use this:

```
int userChoice ;
        try{
        userChoice =scnr.nextInt();//<-- use this variable
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException ime){
            System.out.println("Error: Menu selection must be an integer! Please try again:");
        }
```

likewise use the same logic inside the if condition also

Comment: I don't think I can use those methods since this is an introductory project. Is there no simpler solution?

Comment: i have not used any additionl methods.. you had the hasNextInt() on a primitive which would not allow the code to compile. I have a the try catch block. If you feel that this is huge for introductory proj, you can use userChoice =scnr.nextInt(); without the surrounding try, catch block. but be warned that you will run into exceptions at runtime if the input is not an integer

Answer (score 0):

Better to go with Switch-Case statement within a loop.
Java JDK 1.7 also supports 'string' in switch-case now.

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
   int userChoice = scnr.nextInt();
   if(userChoice > 0 && userChoice <9){
       // your logic
   }else{
       System.out.println("Invalid choice");
       showMenu();
   }

}catch(Exception e){
   System.out.println("Invalid choice");
   showMenu();
}

public void showMenu(){
     System.out.println("Available Actions:");
     System.out.println("(1) Print Market Prices");
     System.out.println("(2) Print Detailed Statistics");
     System.out.println("(3) Buy Some Sheep");
     System.out.println("(4) Buy a Guard Dog");
     System.out.println("(5) Sell a Sheep");
     System.out.println("(6) Sell a Guard Dog");
     System.out.println("(7) Enter Night Phase");
     System.out.println("(8) Quit");
     System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is correction to be made on the sequence `nextInt()` and `hasNextInt()` is invoked. First one is used to read the value from input, and second is used to see whether the value type is `int`. So you have to invoke `hasNext[Type]()` followed by `next[Type].

Secondly, since `nextInt()` is returning an `int`, so it is incorrect to invoke `hasNextInt()` on the `userChoice` variable.

Let's correct those two first as below.

```
if (scnr.hasNextInt()) {
    int userChoice =  scnr.nextInt();
} else {
    // input is not an int
}
```

Now let's correct your code to get a valid `int`, also to print the instructions and ask for the input again for invalid inputs.

```
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

boolean incorrectInput = true;
int userChoice = -1;

while (incorrectInput) {

    if (scnr.hasNextInt()) {

        userChoice = scnr.nextInt();
        // Variable used for storing what the user's main menu choice

        if (0 >= userChoice || userChoice > 8) {
            System.out.println("Error: Invalid Menu Selection.");
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Available Actions:");
            System.out.println("(1) Print Market Prices");
            System.out.println("(2) Print Detailed Statistics");
            System.out.println("(3) Buy Some Sheep");
            System.out.println("(4) Buy a Guard Dog");
            System.out.println("(5) Sell a Sheep");
            System.out.println("(6) Sell a Guard Dog");
            System.out.println("(7) Enter Night Phase");
            System.out.println("(8) Quit");
            System.out.println("What would you like to do?");

        } else {
            incorrectInput = false;
        }
    } else {
        scnr.next();
        System.out.println("Error: Menu selection must be an integer! Please try again:");
    }
}
System.out.println("userChoice = " + userChoice);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can use the powerful `IntegerValidator` from **Apache Commons Validator**:

```
if (new IntegerValidator().isInRange(Integer value, int min, int max)) {
    // value is in range ...
}
```